# Using an arbitrary area bounded by lines for PDEs?

Tags: differential-equations, image-processing

I have a set of lines I pulled from an image that make a closed loop, pretend it's a unit square for reference. Is there a way to use such an arbitrary region for solving PDEs, and is there a way to select each line and specify boundary conditions for each independently? The structure of the data set is:

```
edges[[line (1-n),start/endpoint (1 or 2),x/y (1 or 2)]]
```

So edges[[2,2,1]] would give the x coordinate of the end point of the second line. The list of points I have is included below for reference.

```
((261.324
937.805

)   (1139.98
937.843

)
(261.324
937.805

)   (261.014
57.1923

)
(1140.95
505.675

)   (705.906
57.3194

)
(1578.03
507.712

)   (1139.98
937.843

)
(261.014
57.1923

)   (705.906
57.3194

)
(1140.95
505.675

)   (1578.03
507.712))
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory Tour (Done; Great), 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Yes, there is.  See the [Finite Element Method User Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't realize everything was compiled there. I can see how to make a mesh if points are organized by vertices and connectivity, but I don't understand what to do if the data is arranged the way I have it. I can re-organize it, I'd just prefer not to if possible.